# Rselenium can't connect to running shiny app

Tags: r, macos, selenium, shiny, rselenium

I configured selenium server in docker. It works ok - I can connect to it, but when I want to interact with running local shiny app Rselenium does not see it. Details below:

I did step-by-step:

- I run selenium server:

  `docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome`
- successfully connected to selenium server:

`remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4445L
                      , browserName = "chrome"
                      , platform = "MAC")`

`> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"`

- run shiny app from terminal (in separate r session):

`> shiny::runApp(file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "apps", "shinytestapp"), port = 6012)
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6012`

- and then tried to do some tests:

`remDr$navigate("localhost:6012")
appTitle <- remDr$getTitle()[[1]]
expect_equal(appTitle, "Shiny Test App")`

and got error:

`Error: 'appTitle' not equal to "Shiny Test App".
1/1 mismatches
x[1]: "localhost"
y[1]: "Shiny Test App"`

- after all I made a screenshot:

`remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)`

and it looks like this:

[image]

Do you have idea why RSelenium does not see shiny app running locally?

Comment: @ jdharrison I mounted docker using command your command and it looks like this: `PORTS: 0.0.0.0:6012->6012/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4445->4444/tcp` but RSelenium still doesn't see shiny app. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out with a **LOT OF HELP from @jdharrison**.

First make docker compose file (be careful with indentations - one indention must be 2 spaces) and save as `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ropensci:
    image: rocker/ropensci
    ports:
      - "8788:8787"
    links:
      - selenium:selenium
      - shiny:shiny
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "4445:4444"
    links:
      - shiny:shiny
  shiny:
    image: rocker/shiny
    container_name: shiny
    volumes:
      - ~/Users/username/services/volumes/shiny/apps:/srv/shiny-server/
      - ~/Users/username/services/volumes/shiny/logs:/var/log/
      - ~/Users/username/services/volumes/shiny/packages:/home/shiny/
```

or download: https://codeshare.io/2j4yLB

then run `docker-compose up` from folder where `docker-compose.yml` file is.

- Add your apps to `/home/username/services/volumes/shiny/apps`
- To navigate to your app from selenium use `http://shiny:3838/myapp`

To check if it works you can save below code as `app.R` in: `~/Users/username/services/volumes/shiny/apps/example/`:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and run:

```
library(RSelenium) 
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "selenium", port = 4444L, browser = "chrome") 
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url = "http://shiny:3838/example")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

If everything is ok you should see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Yeah docker compose is the way to go on this .

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achive this. Easiest way is to run docker in `--net=host` mode. This will mean mean selenium server runs on the default port 4444

```
docker run -d --net=host selenium/standalone-chrome&
```

Your docker container will now have access to the HOST localhost.

To run on a non default PORT you can pass docker a selenium env variable:

```
docker run -d --net=host -e SE_OPTS="-port 4445" selenium/standalone-chrome
```

Comment: When I run docker like this I can't connect to docker on port 4444: `Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refuse`. I work on mac osx - does it matter?

Comment: Yes port 4444 sometimes seems an issue on MAC. You can set the docker container to run on an alternative as outlined above.

Comment: Still same error :`Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused`. Maybe I should reconfigure something? Maybe I should do something with proxy settings? Or something else?

Comment: Yes it appears there are issues with MAC and --net=host https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1031 . The preferred option would be to run shiny server as a container also then networking is straight forward.

Comment: But I have running docker container with rstudio and if I try : `remDr$navigate(url = "localhost:8787"); remDr$getTitle()[[1]]` I get: `localhost` too. It looks like `-p` mapping doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Your shiny app is running on the HOST machine. This needs to be running as a container. This container would then be able to communicate with the selenium server container.

Comment: See https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/102 for details on using docker compose and communication between containers running rstudio etc and container running selenium

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152770/discussion-between-taz-and-jdharrison).